# Adding a key to an animated ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to animate plots in R using ggplot2 and gganimate. This is the code for a plot. I would like to add a key that specifies which color corresponds to which continent but I can't figure it out.

```
install.packages('gapminder', 'ggplot2', 'gganimate', 'gifski')

p5 <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, colour = country)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = country_colors) +
    scale_size(range = c(2, 12)) +
    scale_x_log10() +
    labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'GDP per capita', y = 'Life expectancy') +
    transition_time(year) +
    ease_aes('linear')

animate(p5)
anim_save('plot.gif')
```

[image: The animated plot]

In the third line, if I change show.legend = TRUE

```
geom_point(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = TRUE)
```

I get this as the plot
[image: When it is true]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe just use `aes(colour = continent)` and `scale_colour_manual(values = continent_colors)` and take out `show.legend=FALSE`. It's not really easy to fill with one value but use completely different values on the legend.

Comment: @akrun that is not changing anything I still get the same gif

Comment: @MrFlick I get the gif with the key but there are no data points on the plot

Comment: Are you sure you changed  to `continent_colors` rather than `country_colors` with `scale_color_manual`? Did you remove the `show.legend=FALSE` or set `show.legend=TRUE`? You can turn off just the size legend with `scale_size(range = c(2, 12), guide=FALSE)`